# I've created a quiz however I'm not sure how to implement the capturing of the buttons pressed to check against the answer using Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've got four buttons and a textView. The text in the textView is retrieved from Parse.com using the following code:

```
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> quizOne = ParseQuery.getQuery("Quiz");
    quizOne.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(ParseObject reqDetails, ParseException e) {

            if (quizOne != null) {
                Log.d("quizOne", "Got it");
                //Retrieve Age
                String gettheQuestion = reqDetails.getString("questionOne");
                TextView getQone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quesOne);
                getQone.setText(gettheQuestion);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Successfully Recieved Question",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {
                Log.d("quizOne", "Question not retreived.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Can't Get Details, Check Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
```

and here is the code for the buttons:

```
 optionAq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (optionAq.equals(optionAq)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Quiz.this, Question2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    optionBq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Quiz.this, Question2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });

    optionCq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Quiz.this, Question2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });

    optionDq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Quiz.this, Question2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });
```

I want to be able to capture the buttons pressed and show like a result screen after. How would I go by doing this, any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: There is just one possible answer, right?

Comment: Then you should use four RadioButton, instead. That way, you can only select one final answer. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Comment: @joan2fast4u - Yes that is correct, only right answer and how would I go by implementing this into my code? Just change the buttons to RadioButtons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those `onClickListeners`. You just need a `RadioGroup` with multiple `RadioButtons` inside it. You have to include it in your XML layout, like this:

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/optionAq"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="A" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/optionAb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="B" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/optionCb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="C" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/optionDb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="D" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Then, in your `Activity`, you have to change your `Buttons` to `RadioButtons`.

Then add the method `onRadioButtonClicked()` that will be invoked if any of the `RadioButtons` is selected.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v){
        Log.i("Answer", "Answer is "+ ((RadioButton)v).getText());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Quiz.this, Question2.class);
        //send the answer to the next Activity if yo need
        intent.putExtra("answer", ((RadioButton)v).getText());
        //start next Activity
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

According to your implementation, that is launching a new `Activity` once a `RadioButton` is clicked, this is a good approach.

There are many other approaches, like using `radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` to get the selected `RadioButton` id.

Anyway, you can learn this and more in the URL I provided in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much Joan2fast4u, one slight problem. I've used the code you gave me however, how am I supposed to show a results screen? In other words, how do I capture what options have been pressed then show  a score on the next screen for e.g.?

Comment: You can do that when the user selects an answer. My code is doing that inside onRadioButtonClicked() method. Then, in your Question2 Activity, you have to extract the answer from your Intent extras.